# Listing files in hdfs and appending the output to a text file

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I want to list the files in hadoop based on a condition and append the output to a text file.  Below is the commands which I am using

```
hadoop fs -ls /path/ | grep 'xxx' | awk '{print $8}' >> /hdfs_path/test.txt
```

when I execute the above command it says  the below error

> -bash: /hdfs_path/test.txt: No such file or directory

but the file exists in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that stdout redirection is only aware of your local filesystem, and knows nothing about Hadoop and cannot natively write to it.  You need to stick with the `hadoop fs` or newer `hdfs dfs` commands for hdfs interactions.

Try [appendToFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#appendToFile) as your piped command.

Usage: `hdfs dfs -ls /your/hdfs/path | grep 'xxx' | hdfs dfs -appendToFile - hdfs://your.hdfs.system/your/hdfs/path/paths.txt`

The only other alternative I have is to save the output to your local filesystem and upload that to HDFS after you're done if you need it there.